# Child Lighting Menorah in Shul

Tags: chanuka, minor-katan-child, synagogue

May a Child light the Menorah in Shul being that it is not the real lighting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per "Children In Halacha" by Rabbi Simcha Bunim Cohen the Shul's Chanukah Menorah may be kindled by a child of Chinuch age.